# How to use pre_render_form of gravity form wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to modify the rendering of a form create with wordpress plugins: Gravity form. By default they render the form in ul tag but I want to render it in div.

I know they are a hook called pre_render_form.
But when I parse the form and change the display I don't know how to display it in my html page.
My html page is displaying with twig and i call the gravity form with shortcode.
I follow the exemple 3 of [this page](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/). In this code I understand they create a content value in the array of the form. But I don't know how they use it in there html page.

could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really disappointed in this community, I thought you were there to help people in need. But not, everyone prefers to put negative points or delete comments.

I wasn't asking to give me the answer/the source code, just to have a conversation to better understand. Don't tell me I didn't look around, I can tell you that I wasted hours looking for explanations on the internet. I think I went back, read different article several times but I stay at the same point.